# How do I create a link to Ask Different chat from Ask Different main?

Tags: support

I've seen links to chat (so as not to have a conversation in the comments).

How do I create one? I've searched the meta here and unfortunately unable to find the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways.

[chat] expands to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat and is named [Ask Different Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) which when called from the main site goes to the site chat room list (but only on the main site).

You can always copy the direct room links and embed a link shorthand using [name](URL) inline syntax as well as the [markdown method][1]

[1]: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat